# How will Google Chrome show bookmarks first in Omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I was trying to visit en.wikipedia.org and the Omnibox always auto-completes en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_I_Typed_Manually_Before. This is not what I want.

I have enabled "Disable 'shortcuts' in the omnibox. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS" in chrome://flags but is does not work. I do not know whether they are even talking about the same thing.

How can I redress this?

Comment: I’m using an older version of Chromium at the moment, so I can’t check, but I see the following Flags entry: `Enable better omnibox history matching - Enables substring and multi-fragment matching within URLs from history.` It sounds like it may have been renamed to the one you mentioned, but if not, then see if it’s disabled.

Comment: I have tried to alter every entry related to Omnibox in Flags but none of them worked. I guess I should stop syncing URL history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Wikipedia from bookmarks solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

type in the omnibox : bm and press the (tab) key then type the name of your bookmark. This works to go to that bookmark direct. No need to use the mouse.

if you type only b and press the (tab) you will see your bookmark in bookmark manager

Comment: Does not work as of Feb 2019.  I hadn't checked before, but now it just autocompletes to the first result that matches **b** or **bm**.